# How to dynamically merge 20 columns for different row with fixed col range in java apache poi

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, merge, apache-poi

I am reading an excel file from the input which is having 30 columns with prefilled data in each column.

I have to read only three columns , 1 column, 2 column and 3rd column as combined from 3 to 23 and have to write these values in db. From 3 to 23 col, its all string values. Now I want to merge these 20 col as one col and insert it into database.

```
CellRangeAddress range = CellRangeAddress.valueOf("C:Y");

sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(row.getRowNum(), row.getRowNum(),
                    range.getFirstColumn(), range.getLastColumn()));
```

In my for loop m changing the row for each new records but range of column remains same.

sheet.addMergedRegion returns an integer which I try to get from row.getCell(i) --> i is the integer value returned from addMergedRegion() method, which eventually return only one Column.

So I am not able to find all 20 merged col as one col so that I can read that from row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue()

**Note : I want to dynamically merge for different row with fixed col range**

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding your question.  You have a 30 column spreadsheet.  You want to create output rows that consist of column 1, column 2, and columns 3 to 23, one column 3 to 23 at a time.  In other words, you want to output 21 rows of 3 columns for each input row of the spreadsheet.  Do I have this correct?

Comment: Yes you are right, i have to save these 3 columns in a database, 1 col, 2 col and col 3-23 as one col, for every row of excel  @GilbertLeBlanc